# Auditing Jetty Client requests and responses

Tags: jetty

I have a requirement to count the jetty transactions and measure the time it took to process the request and get back the response using JMX for our monitoring system.

I am using Jetty 8.1.7 and I can’t seem to find a proper way to do this. I basically need to identify when request is sent (due to Jetty Async approach this is triggered from thread A) and when the response is complete (as the oncompleteResponse is done in another thread).

I usually use ThreadLocal for such state in other areas I need similar functionality, but obviously this won’t work here.

Any ideas how to overcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use jetty's async requests you basically have to subclass ContentExchange and override its methods. So you can add an extra field to it which would contain a timestamp of when the request was sent, and use it later in your onResponseComplete() method to measure the processing time. If you need to know the time when your request was actually sent to the server instead of when it was created you can override the onRequestCommitted() and onRequestComplete() methods.